# How can i show the selected items as comma separated in the Multi select dropdown text field in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, i am trying to do show the selected items as comma separated in the Multi select drop down text field is it possible to do and how can i do this can any one tell me. sample image is link [[As Shown in figure]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT12a.png)

I tried:

.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server" UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"><Style DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200"/></asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

.CS

```
      public void ddlsbind()
    {
    string str=string.Empty;
                string query = "select distinct col1 from Collection where sample='" + ddl2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "' and col1 IS NOT NULL";            
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);        
                ddlInsurance.DataSource = dt;
                ddlInsurance.DataTextField = "col1";
                ddlInsurance.DataValueField = "col1";
                ddlInsurance.DataBind();
    }
```

Can anyone help me to how to do this.
Thank you

Comment: So what is not working in your code spart from the fact that it's open for sql-injection(always use parametrized queries)?

Comment: It's working fine but i need to display what i select items i need to display in the textfield can you please see once my figure i update my question thank you

Comment: You want your text field to display a comma separated list of all checked items - is that correct?

Comment: Loop through each selected item on the selectedIndexChanged event and create a comma separated string builder. Finally convert this string builder to string and assign it to your text field.

Comment: Or do a List<string> and add to it for each checked name, then do textField.Text = String.Join(",",myList);

Comment: Hi Shannon Holsinger, yes correct i want exactly same like that.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psuedoCode:

```
private void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    List<string> checkedList = new List<string>();
    foreach(checkbox c in dropdown1){
        if(c.Checked){
            checkedList.Add(c.Value/Text/Whatever);
        }
    }
    myTextField.Text = String.Join(",",checkedList);
 }
```

The code you're looking for is specifically set forth in the documentation for your control:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    List<String> CountryID_list = new List<string>();
    List<String> CountryName_list = new List<string>();
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in ddchkCountry.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
       {
           CountryID_list.Add(item.Value);
           CountryName_list.Add(item.Text);
       }
       lblCountryID.Text = "Country ID: "+ String.Join(",", CountryID_list.ToArray());
       lblCountryName.Text = "Country Name: "+ String.Join(",", CountryName_list.ToArray());
   } 

}
```

- See more at: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/dropdowncheckboxes-or-drop-down-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-1100.aspx#sthash.PUd43B3a.dpuf

In your specific case, since text and value are the same, you only need one list:

```
   protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
     //List<String> CountryName_list = new List<string>();
     foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in dropdown1.Items)
     {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            //CountryID_list.Add(item.Value);
            checkedList.Add(item.Text);
        }
        //I don't know the ID/name of your textbox. You need to change that here:
         myTextBox.Text = String.Join(",", checkedList);
         //lblCountryName.Text = "Country Name: "+ String.Join(",", CountryName_list.ToArray());
     } 
}
```

Change the textbox from MyTextBox to the actual name of the textbox you are using and that should do it. Take a look at how I modified the sample code and use that to modify your own from here on out. Look at what it's doing.

**Additional Information** remember that the control you are using is custom, so it will have properties/methods/settings not fully available through VS intellisense in the manner that standard controls are. You'll have to visit http://saplin.blogspot.com/2011/05/dropdowncheckboxes-using-control.html to see how to manage your custom control.

*Finally,* I'd suggest staying away from custom controls until you understand a little bit more about coding .Net Web Applications - stick to standard controls with well-documented features/parameters that you can easily look up from multiple sources. Venture into custom controls (or create your own - they're easy) after you've mastered the basics.

Comment: That's because it's pseudocode. I can't give you specific code without knowing your code. This is to give you an idea - if you want specifics, I'll need the name of your textbox and what you're tying the list to in the dropdown (is it value, name, id, what)?

Comment: I updated my binding the multi select dropdown code.can you please check once

Comment: Ok let's start from scratch - what master control are you using? I don't have a DropDownCheckBoxes class. Is that part of an extension library or something?

Comment: I found one at CodePlex https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/ is this the one you're using?

Comment: I found that code can you see this once [link]http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/dropdowncheckboxes-or-drop-down-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-1100.aspx

Comment: Revised my answer accordingly. Please remember to select the answer so this question gets closed. Let me know if you need anything further. Cheers!